# How do I access this variable without a global?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to figure out how to make this work.

```
function foo(a) {
  $('#this-button').show();
}

function buttonClicked() {
  //get access to var a
}
```

HTML

```
<button id="this-button" onclick="buttonClicked();">
```

This is a simplified version of what I have but the idea is the same.

foo takes a variable, and then makes a button visible.  When the button is clicked, I want to do more things with var a.

So like wait until the button is clicked to continue the function?

Can't seem to figure it out.

Thanks

Comment: why don't you want to use a global?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bind the click handler using jQuery. You can use [jQuery.Proxy](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) to bind `a` as an argument:

```
function foo(a) {
    $('#this-button').show().click( $.proxy( buttonClicked, null, a ) );
}

function buttonClicked(a) {
    // Use a here
}
```

and remove the JavaScript from your html attribute:

```
<button id="this-button" />
```

EDIT, if all you want to do is execute some code after the button is clicked, you can do something like this:

```
function foo(a) {

    // Code up here executes before the button is clicked

    $('#this-button').show().unbind( 'click.foo' ).one( 'click.foo', function ( ) {
        console.log( a );
        // This code executes after the click, and has access to a
    } );

    // Code down here executes before the button is clicked

}
```

Comment: What if I end up calling foo multiple times?

Comment: @NorCalKnockOut Then what `a` do you want `buttonClicked` to act on, assuming each time you call `foo` you pass in a different value for `a`?

Comment: Sorry for my confusion, but I don't understand the question.  `a` is different everytime `foo` is called.

Comment: @NorCalKnockOut So you're saying you want `foo` to do some work, then wait for a button click, then continue executing?

Comment: Yeah exactly.  So foo get an id, queries a database for some objects, checks there status, and updates a table.  When the table gets updated, the button is shown to save `a`.

Comment: Can you explain the unbind('click.foo').one part?

Comment: @NorCalKnockOut That's to unbind any click handlers that were previously bound by foo, to the button, in case `foo` is called multiple times, without the button being clicked in between. It guarantees that the callback only executes once per button click. You can safely remove that part if you have a guarantee that foo is not called again until after the click, or if you want to make sure that the click handler executes once for each call to foo if there were multiple calls to foo before the click.

Comment: JSFiddle with unbind: http://jsfiddle.net/13o368L7/ and without: http://jsfiddle.net/13o368L7/1/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80920/discussion-between-norcalknockout-and-paulpro).

Answer (score 1):

You use an [event handler content attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#event-handler-content-attributes). Those have access to:

- Properties defined in the element (if any)
- Properties defined in the form owner of the element 8if any)
- Properties defined in the document
- Properties in the global object (i.e. global variables).

Therefore, you can add the variable as a property of the element:

```js
function foo(a) {
  $('#this-button').show().prop('myProp', a);
}
function buttonClicked(a) {
  alert(a);
}
foo(123);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="this-button" onclick="buttonClicked(myProp)">Click me</button>
```

Of course, using an [event handler IDL attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#event-handler-idl-attributes) or an event listener would be a better practice.

Answer (score 0):

This is the reason for a global, either that or create an object with functions that could use closure.

Comment: why the downvote?  somebody care to explain?  If he does not want to pollute the global namespace than an object would work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can always access the global scope:

```
window.a = a;
```

But this is generally bad practice. Can you restructure the code so that both places have a available.

Ie

```
var a = {};  //set a

$("#button").click(function(){
    // a is available here
});

foo(a);
```

Comment: I'm trying to find a way to restructure.  I want to run foo until a certain spot, then wait for a button click to continue.

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<button id="this-button">
```

JS

```
   function foo(a) {
      $('#this-button').show();

      $('#this-button').click(buttonClicked);

    function buttonClicked() {
      //a can be accesed here
    }

    }
```

Put buttonClicked method inside foo to get access of variable a

Answer (score 0):

There's a few different ways to skin this cat but one method is to use a closure to capture the `a` variable:

```
var myButton = document.getElementById('this-button');

function foo(a) {
    myButton.addEventListener("click", buttonClicked(a));
    ...
}

function buttonClicked(a) {
    return function() {
        console.log('buttonClicked', a);
    }
}

foo('Success!');
```

In this case, the function `buttonClicked` returns a function that captures the value of `a` when run by the `foo` function. This resulting function is then passed to the `event handler` and run when triggered.

See the fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/ToddT/ae5h1src/

Comment: Does the event listener get added everytime I call foo?

Comment: In this case, it would. My example is the very simplest implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You could use HTML5 `localstorage`...

```
function foo(a) {
  $('#this-button').show();
  localStorage.setItem("variable_a", a); // variable in localstorage =variable_a
}

function buttonClicked() {
  localStorage.getItem('variable_a');
  //get access to var a
}
```

HTML5 localstorage allows you to store data on the client browser, and you can access it via `getItem()`... more info here: [[w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)], [[jenkov.com](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/html5/local-storage.html)]

Comment: Using `localStorage` just to solve a scoping issue seems overkill. At least use `sessionStorage`, which will be cleared when the browser closes.

Answer (score 0):

Use closure.

```js
    (function(){
      var dummy_a;
      function foo(a) {
        //$('#this-button').show();
           dummy_a = a;
      }
    
      function buttonClicked() {
        //get access to var a
        alert(dummy_a)
      }
        foo(2)
        buttonClicked()
    })();
```